# Knockout tutorial not working in JsFiddle

Tags: knockout.js, jsfiddle

I am trying to get an example of Knockout working in JsFiddle.

[JsFiddle Here:](http://jsfiddle.net/DavyCassidy/ETpPz/)

This all works on the Knockout website and this code is taken directly from there.

Everything works as expected in JSFiddle too except the REMOVE function.

Does anyone know why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you need to tell KnockoutJS that you want to pass current data to `removeSeat`. Do this with JavaScript's `bind` function like this:

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeSeat.bind($root, $data)">Remove</a>
```

The first parameter of `bind` is a context, i.e. what will be accessed via `this` inside the function. Other parameters are normally passed to function. Read more about this in [the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note_2_accessing_the_event_object_or_passing_more_parameters).

Comment: Hmm, unfortunetly I do not have an answer for this.